# Call an ActionCreator from another ActionCreator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I need to call an ActionCreator from another

**ducks/products.ts** - ActionCreator and Reducers of Products...

```
import { setStock } from './Store.ts';
//....
export const addProduct = (product: IProduct) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => IState,
  { auth }: IServices
) => {
    dispatch(fetchStart());

    const response = await Axios.post('/api/products', product)

    const producto = response.data as IDataProduct

    // # I need to call SetStock() 
    // # [Try 1] to Call
    setStock(producto)

    // # [Try 2] to Call
    // return (dispatch2: any) => {
      //  dispatch2(
         //setStock(producto._id)
        //  )
    // }

    dispatch(fetchSucess(producto))
};
```

I saw an example that used **try 2**, but it doesn't work, and the **first try** does nothing,

**ducks/stores.ts**

```
export const setStock = (product: any) => async (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => any,
  { auth, db }: IServices
) => {
  console.log('INIT SETSTOCKACTIONCREATOR....')
  dispatch(fetchStart());
  try {
    const ref = db.collection("stores").doc(storeId);    
    await ref.update({ [product._id]: product.newStock });

    dispatch(updateSucess({ _id: storeId, stock: product.newStock, productId: product.productId }));

  } catch (error) {    
    dispatch(fetchError(error));
  }
};
```

I can't do a **Dispatch(setStock(producto))** because I get the following from the typescript:

Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch, getState: () => any, { auth, db }: IServices) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.

Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch, getState: () => any, { auth, db }: IServices) => Promise' but required in type 'AnyAction'

Comment: Your thunk actions need to return a promise (especially setStock). Then in addProduct you can do: `await dispatch(setStock(producto))` you also pass product id to setStock but I think setStock expects the product itself.

Comment: I can't do that, i get a typescript error, missing type property and setStock is not assignable to AnyAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to dispatch the setStock action like `dispatch(setStock(producto._id))` which is similar to what you do for `fetchStart`

```
export const addProduct = (product: IProduct) => async (
  dispatch: ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>,
  getState: () => IState,
  { auth }: IServices
) => {
    dispatch(fetchStart());

    const response = await Axios.post('/api/products', product)

    const producto = response.data as IDataProduct

    dispatch(setStock(producto._id))


    dispatch(fetchSucess(producto))
};
```

Comment: I can't, I get this from the typescript when I try to do that,                                     **Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, getState: () => any, { auth, db }: IServices) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>, getState: () => any, { auth, db }: IServices) => Promise<void>' but required in type 'AnyAction'**

Comment: OP probably wants to wait for setStock to finish so setStock should return, setStock seems to receive a product and not the id of the product so something like `await dispatch(setStock(product))`. I'm assuming thunk is used so you can await other thunk actions.

Comment: @AndresGaibor Import Dispatch type [from thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/103#issuecomment-260968362)

Comment: import ThunkAction from redux-thunk as use it for type Dispatch . Check this article for more info: ThunkAction<Promise<void>, {}, {}, AnyAction>